# Count the number of groups of the same value in a matrix row in R

Tags: r, count, sequence

In the example below I am showing the first row of a matrix from a simulation in R. The row represents one indivudual in my simulation and columns represent days. If an individual has fever in a given day, then that is coded as "1" in this matrix. I want to output the number of times an individual got fever. In the example below this would be 4 times (4 sets of 1s). Does anyone know how to code this to count adjacent 1s as a single occurrence?

> out_fever[1,]

```
 [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We loop over the rows with `apply` and use `rle` to calculate the number of blocks of 1 in each row

```
out_fever$n_fever <- apply(out_fever, 1,  function(x)  with(rle(x), sum(values==1)))
```

Using a reproducible example for the first row

```
v1 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,  
      1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
with(rle(v1),  sum(values == 1))
#[1] 4
```